# JSON - Encoding a List of Serializable Objects

Tags: python, json, class, object

I have a the following code. In essence, there are two classes - Lego Themes which acts as a container for Lego Theme objects. I have implemented a method "saveThemes()" that basically iterates through the themes - converts the individually stored Lego Objects into JSON and then adds them to a variable (resultantJson).

However, I appreciate this is a bit of a 'hack'. Should I be able to do a json.dumps() of the self__.themes directly (it currently says the object is serializable)?

```
import json


class LegoThemes:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__themes = []

    def saveThemes(self):
        resultantJson = ""

        for theme in self.__themes:
            resultantJson += json.dumps(theme.__dict__)

        # TODO: Output resultantJSON to .JSON file.
        return resultantJson

    # TODO: implement loadThemes(self)

    def addTheme(self, theme):
        self.__themes.append(theme)


class LegoTheme:
    def __init__(self, title, description, thumbnailImage, logoImage, url):
        self.__title = title
        self.__description = description
        self.__thumbnailImage = thumbnailImage
        self.__logoImage = logoImage
        self.__url = url

    def getTitle(self):
        return self.__title


testThemeOne = LegoTheme(
    "Test Theme One Title",
    "Test Theme One Description.",
    "Test Theme One Thumbnail Image",
    "Test Theme One Logo Image",
    "Test Theme One URL",
)

testThemeTwo = LegoTheme(
    "Test Theme Two Title",
    "Test Theme Two Description.",
    "Test Theme Two Thumbnail Image",
    "Test Theme Two Logo Image",
    "Test Theme Two URL",
)

testThemeThree = LegoTheme(
    "Test Theme Three Title",
    "Test Theme Three Description.",
    "Test Theme Three Thumbnail Image",
    "Test Theme Three Logo Image",
    "Test Theme Three URL",
)

legoThemes = LegoThemes()

legoThemes.addTheme(testThemeOne)
legoThemes.addTheme(testThemeTwo)
legoThemes.addTheme(testThemeThree)

print(legoThemes.saveThemes())
```

Comment: btw the string returned from `saveThemes()` is technically *not* json.

Comment: @quamrana Because they are not encapsulated within one JSON 'string'?

Comment: If you look on the [website](http://json.org) the only allowed top level objects are list `[]` or object `{}`. You have to ask yourself what would you expect a `json` decode of the result of `saveThemes()` to produce?

Comment: @quamrana excellent, thank you fully understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert a list of the `__dict__` member as `json`:

```py
    def saveJson(self):
        return json.dumps([t.__dict__ for t in self.__themes])
```